# How to display N number of inline-block elements of same size vertically aligned?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to show a number of items of fixed size in a container. The number of items is variable, the size of each item is always the same. Items in all rows (including the last row) should be left aligned.

The problem is that the child items become misaligned vertically depending on the number of lines of text in them:

```css
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
</div>
```

Expected behavior:

[image: Expected behavior]

Comment: _All_ this needs, is some proper `vertical-align`.

Comment: vertical-align:top

Comment: I confirm that both comments above are correct, as well. Any `vertical-align` (including top) seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it.

```css
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.child {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #bbbbbb;
  margin: 0.5em;
  height: 5em;
  width: 8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2</div>
  <div class="child">1<br/>2<br/>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! For the record, I was trying 'flex' but I haven't tried 'inline-flex', thanks for your insight!